# Android x86 Marshmallow + ODROID-VU7 touch does not work

Tags: android, touchscreen, android-x86

I installed the marshmallow version of android x86.
Everything works fine except the touch screen VU7.

This is the screen: http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G144549683088

Somebody could help me?

Thank you!

PS: I do not know how to compile an x86 android image, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What SBC do you use?

If u don't use ODROID's SBC, you need to port ODROID-VU7 touch driver.

If not, check Android image version. old version of Hardkernel's Android image doesn't support VU7 touch.

Also, why don't you use Hardkernel's forum and wiki? there are information what you need.